# Is it possible to make a custom emoji keyboard in IOS 8

Tags: ios, swift, emoji, ios-keyboard-extension

So I've seen a lot of apps that allow you to "make your own emojis" but they actually just make a picture that you can share. Would there be a way for the user to make his own entire keyboard? Let's say of the user adds the app's keyboard in settings, can he now from the app add his own edited picture as one of the keys on the keyboards? I've found things about custom keyboards but it only seems to allow for characters to be inserted...

Answer (score 1):

In software development, anything is possible.
Although I don't have the skills to make one at this moment, here's how it should work.

1. User 1 makes a "Emoji 1", "Emoji 2", etc.
2. He shares to User 2.
   2a. An array of "Emoji 1", "Emoji 2", etc. is created.
   2b. The array is sent to User 2. User 1 can uploads the array to a database and User can download it, or (via Airdrop or the like) User 1 can shoot it right to User 2.
3. User 2 gets the array.
4. User 2's device opens up the array, and puts "Emoji 1", "Emoji 2", etc. into the keyboard.

I hope this helps!!!